# Android project error debugging in Eclipse

Tags: android

How can I debug an error that would require modification of an android private library file? I can't run the android project because eclipse prompts me to remove the error, which says:

> This class should be public (android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.HomeView)

In my understanding that file is located in android private container. How can I remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

Hey first you go project in top of eclipse and clean the project.. If error is still there then checkout libraries from right click on project and then properties and android..

Answer (score 0):

very common issue, open the `project.properties` file and be sure to have

```
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7
```

if that doesn´t work i found here @ stackoverflow this:

Go to appcompat_v7 library -> `Properties` -> `Android Lint Preferences` -> `Instantiatable` -> Select "`Warning`" severity.

[image]

**[Android Lint Checks](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks)**

> **Instantiatable**
>   Summary: Ensures that classes registered in the manifest file are instantiatable
>
> Priority: 6 / 10 Severity: Warning Category: Correctness
>
> Activities, services, broadcast receivers etc. registered in the
>   manifest file must be "instiantable" by the system, which means that
>   the class must be public, it must have an empty public constructor,
>   and if it's an inner class, it must be a static inner class.